# how to close connection MS access with Apache using php

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, odbc

i try to delete .mdb Ms Access file after using it and get this error:

> the action cant be complete because the file is open in apache

[image: Screenshot]

try close manually with

```
$this->db->close();
```

or

```
odbc_close();
```

try close browser as well and problem still exist
there is a way to delete the file using script without restart apache?

Comment: [I have the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024428/cannot-close-odbc-connections), I suspect it's a bug and I never found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd stop Apache, then delete the file.

Open services then find Apache and stop the service.

The file can't be used by Apache if Apache isn't running.

Comment: yes, thats may a solutuion to delete the file, but actually i want to doing that with php, user can upload the file again, and system can delete after using it, is there  a way to doing that without restart apache?

Comment: I think you will need to rephrase you question so that that is clear. I'm afraid I can't help you with that.

Comment: can u give me reference or link with the same problem sir? , and sorry, did u mean you cant help me is there is no way or u dont know yet sir?