# Cannot close ODBC connections

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc, jet

I use `odbc_connect()` to open a DSN-less connection with a Microsoft Access file under PHP/5.6.21 and write into the file:

```
$conn = odbc_connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=D:\\Path\\To\\Output.mdb', '', '');
```

Apparently, both `odbc_close($conn)` nor `odbc_close_all()` destroy the resource but don't really close the connection. As a result:

- I cannot move or delete the file when I'm done because I get *file is in use by another process* error messages.
- I cannot write as many files as I need because I get *Too many client tasks*.

Is it possible to effectively close an ODBC connection to Microsoft Access from PHP or the feature is just not implemented?

Comment: As PHP manual say: This function will fail if there are open transactions on this connection. The connection will remain open in this case. After `odbc_close($conn)` try `odbc_errormsg($conn)`, what will it show?

Comment: @gofr1 It returns an empty string. I'm not opening any transaction, not at least intentionally—I mean I never call `odbc_autocommit()` or `odbc_commit()`.

Comment: After `odbc_close..` in folder `D:\Path\To\` can you find temp Access file with `ldb` extension? As I know when someone (or something) is working with `*.mdb` there is always `*.ldb` file.

Comment: @gofr1 There's an `*.ldb` file and it gets removed when I call `odbc_close()` (so that function actually does *something*). I wouldn't be surprised if the open handle on the `*.mdb` file is due to Microsoft ODBC driver...

Comment: That could be a problem with ODBC, you can try ADO. There is a working example here http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php#35331